# Item in ItemsControl to have different style than all the others which are in DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, datatemplate, datatrigger

Here's my xmal code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myObjects}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">                            
                <TextBlock FontSize="24pt" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding MyClassTranslation.MyClassName[0]}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The problem which I'm facing is that I want the first item in the ItemsControl to have different style than the ones in the DataTemplate. How do I do this? I tried using data triggers but with no success, I don't know how to apply it to the first item.

Comment: Have a look at the [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You could also bind your TextBlock's Style property, and use a ValueConverter to return a different style depending on the binded value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using DataTemplateSelector. Thanks to @Rob Jacobs.
I used [this](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector) tutorial/